# How can I alternatively write these functions without using lambda, map, filter?

Tags: python, lambda, list-comprehension

Hello I have two functions that use the lambda,map,filter operators and I would like to know how they could be rewritten in a simpler format.

```
while not all((map(lambda x: G.vertex[x][y], G.vertices())))

v = list((filter(lambda x: not G.vertex[x][y],G.vertices())))
```

The **y** variable represents a Boolean.

Is there a better way to rewrite them that would also increase performance?

Thank you

Comment: You can use [list comprehensions](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk) instead. But I don't think this will change much with respect to the performance.

Comment: You have not told us what `y` is?

Comment: You should explain what each expression is supposed to do. What is even stored inside `G.vertex[x][y]`? is it a boolean, an int, a string???

Comment: The 'y' variable represents a Boolean.

Answer (score 0):

You can use generator expressions and list comprehensions:

```
while not all(G.vertex[x][y] for x in G.vertices()):
    v = [x for x in G.vertices() if not G.vertex[x][y]]
```

In general, `map(f, lst)` is equivalent<sup>1)</sup> to `(f(x) for x in lst)` and `filter(f, lst)` to `(x for x in lst if f(x))`. You can also combine `map(g, filter(f, lst))` to `(g(x) for x in lst if f(x))`. On the other hand, `filter(f, map(g, lst))` is a bit more complex, as you have to apply `g` first. You could write it as `(y for y in (g(x) for x in lst) if f(y))` or `(g(x) for x in lst if f(g(x)))` (but the latter will have to apply `g` twice).

---

<sup>1)</sup> Note that in Python 2, `map` and `filter` return lists, but generators in Python 3.